# using .meas during .op for list of values

Tags: current, resistors, dc, simulation, ltspice

I am using LTSpice and I am trying to run a simulation for multiple resistor values in a DC op pt simulation. I need to measure the resistance at a node as well as the current through the varying resistor. I am using:

`.step param VAR list val1 val2 val3 ... valn`

to simulate the resistor but I cannot seem to find the proper way to get the measurements I need from that. I have tried using

`.meas op RESULT find V(myNode) at VAR = val1`.

to find the voltage for the first value val1 but I can't figure out how to make it run the list or to measure the current through VAR

Comment: [This](https://www.analog.com/en/technical-articles/ltspice-plotting-a-parameter-against-something-other-than-time-e-g-resistance.html) may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this line

`.meas OP I_VAR AVG I(VAR)`

This assumes that you are interested in measuring the average current flowing through a resistor called VAR and the result is saved in a variable called I_VAR. For RMS current replaces AVG with RMS. This line of code is going to be called only if you run a OP (Operation Point) simulation. For transient, you can replace OP with TRAN.

The results can be seen in the erro log (`Ctrl + L`). There you can right click and select plot. A new window will open and then you can plot the current vs. the resistance values.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a DC op point (`.op`), then stepping a value will bring up the waveform window showing the variation of the `.step`ped value as the X-axis. The number of plot points will be as many as the `.step` command has, so it will be easy to simply navigate the cursors with left and right arrow keys.

Otherwise, have you tried this, for example:

```
.meas RESULT find I(R1) at VAR=val1
```

Comment: How would you modify the command '.meas RESULT find I(R1) at VAR=val1' to measure all values of I(R1) for VAR = val1, VAR = val2, VAR = val3 ... VAR = valn?

Comment: @CalebCapps Unless it's a large list of stepped values, with a copy-paste+modify. But if the list is large, your best bet is to actually run a `.tran` simulation, not `.op`, for a short period of time, and only use one `.meas` command, which will be executed for every step, so the current will be measured for all the values of the `.step` command.

Comment: the list I was working with was around 10 values, but with a large variety ranging from 50 to 10k without regular intervals to step. I ended up exporting the trace data which had the exact info I need from the simluation